# How to configure only one consumer per queue in SpringBoot:RabbitMQ?

Tags: spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-rabbit

Application overview: 
There can be multiple dynamic queues created. Each queue should only have one consumer. Only when the consumer has finished processing one message, only then the consumer should pick up the another message.

Here is my configuration:

```
@EnableRabbit
@Configuration
public class RabbitMqSenderConfig {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RabbitMqSenderConfig.class);

    @Value("${spring.rabbitmq.addresses}")
    private String addressURL;


    @Bean
    public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() throws URISyntaxException {
        return new CachingConnectionFactory(new URI(addressURL));
    }

    /**
     * Required for executing adminstration functions against an AMQP Broker
     */
    @Bean
    public AmqpAdmin amqpAdmin() throws URISyntaxException {
        return new RabbitAdmin(connectionFactory());
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageConverter jsonMessageConverter() {
        return new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter();
    }

    @Bean
    public AmqpTemplate rabbitTemplate() throws URISyntaxException {
        final RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate = new RabbitTemplate(connectionFactory());
        rabbitTemplate.setMessageConverter(jsonMessageConverter());
        return rabbitTemplate;
    }


}
```

Listener:

```
public class RabbitMqConsumer extends SimpleMessageListenerContainer {

    public void startConsumers() throws Exception {
        super.doStart();
    }
}
```

Handle message method:

```
public void handleMessage(DeploymentJob deploymentJob) {
    // Deployment running, takes almost 10-15 minutes each
    try {
        System.out.println("deploymentJob.getSocketHandler().getSessions() -> "+deploymentJob.getSocketHandler().getSessions());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Everytime a pull request is created, I send the details to rabbitMQ in a queue named after `target` branch, so that all the pull requests gets validated in queue, and I create a consumer like this.

```
    rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend(repoName, queue_name, deploymentJob);
    RabbitMqConsumer container = new RabbitMqConsumer();
    container.setConnectionFactory(rabbitMqSenderConfig.connectionFactory());
    container.setQueueNames(queue_name);
    container.setConcurrentConsumers(1);
    container.setMessageListener(new MessageListenerAdapter(new ConsumerHandler(), new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter()));
    container.startConsumers();
```

The issue here is it is creating new consumers for each and every message in the queue, which I want to avoid.
And I am not finding a way to limit only one consumer per queue. or to check if the consumer does not exists then don't create a new instance of `RabbitMqConsumer`. Is this possible?

Consumer section

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use a `ConcurrentHashMap` keyed by the queue name to determine which queues you already have a consumer for; when you create a new consumer, add it to the map.

Comment: Also how can I make sure, that only if consumer has finished processing the deployment, then only it should accept new job from queue?

Comment: If the listener container has concurrency=1 (default) and you process the message on the container thread, it will only process one request-at-a-time.

Comment: Can you please tell how to process message on container thread? Is my above code running on container thread?

Comment: Yes; the listener will run on the container thread as long as you don't launch an async process on another thread (e.g. with a `TaskExecutor`).

Comment: One last question,  what if my consumer gets removed from rabbitmq after sometime of inactive period, but my map will still hold the value right? If this is possible,  then how to handle this part? Can i keep my consumer active forever?

Comment: `if my consumer gets removed from rabbitmq` - I am not sure what you mean by that; the consumer doesn't **exist** in RabbitMQ; it is a client-side concept the consumer will remain as long as your app is running (or until you `stop()` the container). If you delete a queue that has an active consumer, the consumer will start throwing exceptions and eventually stop its container(by default).

Comment: So, what i meant is this, I have added an image, the consumer section here has a consumer connection when i create a consumer. But after some period of inactivity when there is no request to consumer, it gets automatically removed.

Comment: i think as the heroku free dyno gets shutdown after 30 minutes of inactivity,  i think because of that the consumer connection also gets removed. This might be reason.

Comment: There is nothing in Spring or RabbitMQ that will do that.